# Convert persistant to detached in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Is delete() a valid mathod to detached object in hibernate. I know about the evict().But in a question
    Which converts persistent object to detached state?
    Options
    delete() evict()
Are both rigth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to have an entity within a *persistent state*, once you have that, you can change entity's state to *detached* by invoking the **evict** method which is a part of Hibernate API.

However, the **delete** method will change entity's state from *persistent* state to *removed* state, ***and not to detached state***. When an Object\Entity is in the *removed* state, it means it's scheduled for deletion. Once you get your persistence context sync with your DB, that Object\row in DB will be removed.

If you're using Hibernate JPA as your underlying implementation of JPA specification, then you should know that:

1. **remove**() method with EntityManager of JPA is same as **delete**() method of Session with Hibernate
2. **detach**() method with EntityManager of JPA is same as **evict**() method of Session with Hibernate